# Keras - One Class CNN - Two inputs one at each step

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to train a One Class CNN but want only train on one class. So to solve the problem of not having a negative class instead of add random images to a 'no-class' label I want to train with noise for those inputs. But I want to input the noise no as a random generated image but as a features vector before the classifier NN, as it is explained at this paper:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.08688.pdf

So one step will come as a features vector from the VGG16 conv layers and the next step I would like to train with a random generated features vector.

[image]

I'm using tf.keras and the Functional API trying to add an extra input to VGG16.
I've tried my own input generator, but I'm not sure if I can achieve it by code and using Keras since I don't know if I can activate different inpunts at each step.
One approach is to extract all the features vectors from the conv layers, generate a similar number of noise vectors and then train the classificator with both the noise generated and the real features.

That will work I guess, but can I do it all in the same model?

Please, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/one-class-neural-network-in-keras-249ff56201c0

Answer (score 0):

If you think slightly creatively, you don't need to have a noise input layer at all.

We can use `GaussianNoise()` from tf.keras, but it needs an input tensor, technically we should pass it a `ones` vector. We can make the intermediate VGG output features to multiply by zero kernels of a dense layer then we can add `ones` bias to it, so we get our placeholder `ones` vector which will be passed to `GaussianNoise`.

Now, you can forget any complex datagenerator, just use your regular data generators or directly numpy array with `fit`.

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG16
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import *
import tensorflow as tf

ip = Input((224,224,3))

base = VGG16((224,224,3))(ip)

# passing vgg features to a zero vector, making everything zero and then adding bias ones to make the output is always 1

dense_ones = Dense(1000, activation='linear', kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.Zeros(), bias_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.Ones())(base)
gaussian = GaussianNoise(0.4)(dense_ones)

concat = Concatenate()([base, gaussian])

learn_feature = Dense(128, activation = 'relu')(concat) # change this part based on your needs
classification = Dense(2, activation = 'sigmoid')(learn_feature)

model = Model(ip, classification)
```

```
Model: "model_5"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_19 (InputLayer)           [(None, 224, 224, 3) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
vgg16 (Model)                   (None, 1000)         138357544   input_19[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                 (None, 1000)         1001000     vgg16[1][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
gaussian_noise_5 (GaussianNoise (None, 1000)         0           dense_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_4 (Concatenate)     (None, 2000)         0           vgg16[1][0]                      
                                                                 gaussian_noise_5[0][0]           
==================================================================================================
Total params: 139,358,544
Trainable params: 139,358,544
Non-trainable params: 0
___________________________________
```

Comment: Thanks Zabir, great approach to append Noise. But still have to solve how to set the concatenate input as two different inputs. What I understand from the paper I'm trying to implement is that the input noise should be labeled as another class so that the output of the classifier has two units

Comment: There is the `learn_feature` and `classification` layer, you can change those I guess, the last layer can have 2 units and a softmax.